# how do we redirect pages in spring mvc

Tags: html, xml, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

ive made a application but what I want to do is. When a user chooses a country it then redirects them to another page with the heading of that country.
   this is my code

```
public class Place {
     @RequestMapping(value="/addcountry")

    public String place(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, 
             defaultValue="PLACE") String name, Model     model) {
        model.addAttribute("name", name);
        return "form/Place";}

    @RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String redirect() {
       return "redirect:form/Country";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/finalPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String finalPage() {
       return "form/Country";
    }
}
```

JSP:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
     pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <form action="some.jsp" class="form">



  <title>choose a country</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>choose your next destination</h1>
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <style>
  * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
 }

 body {
  font: 16px Arial;  
  }


  .autocomplete {
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
 }

 input {
   border: 1px solid transparent;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
   padding: 10px;
   font-size: 16px;
 }

 input[type=text] {
   background-color: #f1f1f1;
   width: 100%;
 }

 input[type=submit] {
   background-color: DodgerBlue;
   color: #fff;
   cursor: pointer;
 }

 .autocomplete-items {
  position: centre;
    border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
   border-bottom: none;
   border-top: none;
   z-index: 99;

  top: 100%;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
 }

 .autocomplete-items div {
    padding: 10px;
   cursor: pointer;
   background-color: #fff; 
   border-bottom: 1px solid #d4d4d4; 
 }


 .autocomplete-items div:hover {
   background-color: #e9e9e9; 
 }


 .autocomplete-active {
   background-color: DodgerBlue !important; 
   color: #ffffff; 
 }
 </style>
</head>     
 <body>

 <h2>Travel the world</h2>

 <p>choose a country you'd like to go</p>


 <form:form method = "GET" action = "/HelloWeb/redirect" autocomplete="off"   action="/action_page.php">
   <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
    <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
  </div>
  <input type=submit value ="lets go"/>
</form>
```

this is not the full Jsp file
 I want to be redirected to another page when a user clicks a submit button I have already made a basic Js page for that and it still doesn't work.
I've been working on it since 2 days with no progress i've used resources online still doesn't work any help would be appreciated

Comment: try removing action="/action_page.php" from form tag and give correct Url in first action. You should be good to go then.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of redirect to view templates path, you redirect to controller mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirect() {
   return "redirect:/finalPage"; // Which is mapped to finalPage()
}
```

But in your case, a simple form action target to "/finalPage" is sufficient. Why do you need a "/redirect" in between?

Comment: I dont  understand what you mean